# HTML2CANVAS image to be sent via email

Tags: html, mailto, html2canvas

This is what i am trying to achieve
When a button is pressed on a specific div in a HTML page, it goes to the HTML2CANVAS function and creates a canvas img. Now i need to attach this image to the body and open an outlook compose box.
1) How to send mail with image embeded in the body from within a web page?
2) How to convert canvas as a displayable image?

Answer (score 0):

1. This function is the answer to your second question. This function converts a div into a base64 image and on complete render it displays the image to a div or you can do accordingly as you want.

   ```
   function getImage(){

           html2canvas($("#divID"), {
               onrendered: function(canvas) {
                   //  For image
                   var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
   //              ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
   //              ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                   ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

                   var convertedImage;
                   $.when(convertedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg')).promise().done(function(){

       $('#finalImg').prop('src', convertedImage)              
                   });  
               }

           });                     

   }
   ```
2. And the answer to your first question is also the same this converted image can be sent as a image in mail.
3. But you cannot send a MIME type in mailto body it can only contains plain text as body..
   for further reference here is a link
   [Sending mail from HTML page with image in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373737/sending-mail-from-html-page-with-image-in-the-body)