# How to place html content in email body

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have on button and On click of button I am opening outlook with subject and email. 
In email body how to open html content. I am able to open plain text but not html

My html deceleration :

```
var tab = <table><tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr></table>">test'/>
```

My on click event :

```
handler : function(){
    window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=+tab";
}
```

Calling tab in body part. Can any please suggest where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Its not possible....

Comment: What is the reason for downvote. Please specify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MailTo with HTML body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put html in a body.
I think this has already been asked here: [Sending mail from HTML page with image in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373737/sending-mail-from-html-page-with-image-in-the-body)
for more details - 
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt