# How to embed an image at mail body when clicking "send by mail" button

Tags: html, image, mailto

I have a list of social sharing buttons on HTML. Clicking each of them allows to send an image (see the codepen sample). I would like to know if there's a way to attach the same image on the "Sending by mail" button, at the mail body.

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.designboom.com/contest/files/copy_0_brain1.jpg">
    Share on Facebook
</a>
<br/>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=pic.twitter.com/HntZUf55tt">
   Share on Twitter
</a>
<br/>
<a href="mailto:?subject=I like this &body=http://www.designboom.com/contest/files/copy_0_brain1.jpg">
    Send by mail
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far I know the only way to achieve this is by using Base64 encoded images. See this answer:

[Sending mail from HTML page with image in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26374026/1600193)

Please keep in mind that you cannot use spaces as character. Email content have to be entity encoded. Otherwise some characters will break your code. Just use `%20` instead of space. For further experiments with encoding you could try [This online encoder](http://clickable-email.ezkode.com/)

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look.

Comment: As far as i see is not possible :-(

Comment: @Danielillo Please keep in mind that you cannot use spaces as character. This breaks the code. Just use "%20" instead of space ;)

Comment: Muchas%20gracias!

Comment: @Danielillo De nada ;) But you could up vote the answer in case this was helpful...